# if/else statement to remove a select option in Jade Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I'm new to Jade and i got the assignment to create a select option in a webpage. Everything seems good until i get an empty option element which is created when the drop-down list is empty and the Page is refreshed. I want to somehow remove this empty option element. I went through most posts here but didn't seem to get any help. Below is my Jade logic.

Jade:

```
#remarksField
   h1#remarksHeader Remarks
   select#shortDesc
      option(value= "")= "---"
        each index in data
         if (index)
           option(value= index.id)= index.short_desc
         // else
```

Don't know how to post a Fiddle because it's part of a large Code but I hope someone gets to help me out here.

[image: How it looks when trying to select an option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra indentation after the first `option` tag causes all of the following options to be inside the first tag. Remove that extra indentation and it should all work:

```
#remarksField
h1#remarksHeader Remarks
select#shortDesc
  option(value= "")= "---"
  each index in data
   if (index)
     option(value= index.id)= index.short_desc
   // else
```

Comment: I tried that already but didn't work. I think an empty object without value is stored in index which is setting the if statement to true, thereby creating the empty option. Now what i need to do is prove if index is not empty or has no error, if it does then there shouldn't be no option element. This is what is getting tedious because I am doing this over Jade

Comment: Rather than checking if `index` exists, try checking if `index.id` exists. Not much more I can do to help without more info. Please mark the answer correct to close the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets around "index" on your if statement.

So it should be like this:

`if index`

You can find out more about if statements here - http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/

Comment: According to the documentation, "it's still regular JavaScript," so the parentheses surrounding a boolean expression are fine

Comment: Ahh ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Add placeholder

```
option(value="1" placeholder="Select")
```

It would avoid it from getting blank on refresh.